# htaccess redirect wordpress folder change

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have a url of http://example.com/wordpres/
I'm going to change this to http://example.com/w/
I currently get a lot of traffic from links already out on the web. How can I redirect everything that went to /wordpress to /w ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^wordpress(.*)$ /directory/path/to/w/$1
```

The above line should match every request coming to your domain with 'wordress' at the start and redirect it to /w/. The '301' tells the browser (and search engines) that the page(s) have moved permenantly. The $1 exists to redirect anything after /wordpress/ and append it to the redirected URL. So if I visit http://example.com/wordpress/this-post/ I would get redirected to http://example.com/w/this-post.

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule wordpress(.*)$ /w$1
```

If doesnt work.. let me know... :)